# Send data from popup to form parent

Tags: php, forms, window

I have a worked example for passing data from child window to parent window 
this is the example :
http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-child3-demo.php
but what I'm looking for is to pass data from div popup and not window popup 
to parent form; 
any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If the div popup is a modal window of some description, i.e. it is a div overlaying the current page but within the same document, then you can do so by listening for the click event on the modal button and when you see this click, taking the value of the input inside the modal.

Assuming your page setup is similar to the example in the link you posted, if you had an input with an id of input1, and a modal containing an input with id input2, and button with an id of button, then this would be a pure javascript method for achieving the effect you describe.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('input1').value = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    }
};
```

Here is a fiddle which shows the function working: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z7hg/

The key thing to remember is that you need a way to query the element which contains the data you want to capture (in this case I gave the input an id of 'input2', which I could query using `document.getElementById('input2').value` and a way to listen to the event which triggers you capturing the data - in this example I created an anonymous function which I bound to the `onclick` event of the element with an id of `button`

Comment: Thank's keir Now when i click on submit popup the data is shown in input form but then the page load and the input value disapear( sorry for my bad english :/)

Comment: sorry, you need to prevent the default action of the button, by passing the event as an argument into your anonymous function, then using the dom method preventDefault(); - i've edited my answer to reflect this.